# How can I have a vertical button group as an appended add-on to an input?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
            <div class="input-prepend input-append">
               <span class="add-on">R</span>
               <input type="text" class="span2" value="0" />
               <div class="add-on btn-group btn-group-vertical">
                  <button class="btn" type="button">+</button>
                  <button class="btn" type="button">-</button>
               </div>
            </div>
```

The above markup will show the + and - buttons side by side and little vertically skewed from one another (obviously, I want them to be one on top of the other).

Basically I want to make a number input box that doesn't absolutely suck (UX-wise) for incrementing and decrementing a number.

Comment: Dumb... in the bootstrap documentation their example wrapping div is "<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical">", so I looked at the css more closely and notice the -vertical class was being overwritten by the btn-group class, so I removed the btn-group [which seems redundent as is] and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `<input type="number">`? It doesn't work in IE natively, but there's a [shim](https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill) that should work for you in IE and other browsers.

Though I'm not generally a fan of W3Schools, their Tryit Editor works fine [for this case](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number).

If you need to code it yourself for whatever reason, [Stuart's got the right answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19673078/2280630)

Comment: The buttons are SOOOOOO tiny. I'll continue to try various css things in the meantime.